# Why ( float: right; ) doesn’t work? Blue box should be on the right

Tags: html, css

I have list of items on the left hand side (coral box) and I need main content to be in the Blue box (on the right next to coral box), but instead they are overlapping (image below)
Here is my HTML and CSS below, what do you think causing the overlapping and how to fix it?
Thanks!

[image: Screenshot image]

```css
.category-tree {
  width: 300px;
  height: 900px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.left-menu li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
}

.left-menu-categories {
  width: 240px;
  color: black;
}

.left-menu-categories a {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.category-tree a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: #b8b8b8
}

.blue-box {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-tree">
  <nav class="left-menu">
    <ul class="left-menu-categories">
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category"><b>Category</b></a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <hr>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="blue-box">
    <p>Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .category-tree width must be greater than blue-box width. Try width:100% and set position relative

Comment: @HakanTurkmen what is `position: relative;` supposed to do? It in this context absolutly meaningless and does nothing. Giving `.category-tree` a width greater then the `.blue-box` wont fix it either. It must be greater then `.blue-box + nav` in order to fit. However this will not fix the fundemantal coding mistake of using float for styling purpose. and being absolutely unresponsive and hardly useable for modern device screens.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `float` for styling purpose. It is a mis-used hack from pre 2012. Since 2012 you have `Flexbox` and since 2015 `Flexbox` and `CSS-Grid` are well established and not causing so many possible issue as `float`. Float was never intended as styling tool just to float images within a paragraph (like newspaper).

Simply use flexbox:

1. Give the wrappe the flex property and change its width to 100% to be responsive.

```
.category-tree {
  width: 100%
  min-height: 900px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
```

2. Give the blue textbox the property `flex-grow: 1;` to consume the remaining space

```css
.category-tree {
  width: 100%
  min-height: 900px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  background-color: coral;
}

.left-menu li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
}

.left-menu-categories {
  width: 240px;
  color: black;
}

.left-menu-categories a {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.category-tree a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: #b8b8b8
}

.blue-box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-tree">
  <nav class="left-menu">
    <ul class="left-menu-categories">
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category"><b>Category</b></a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <hr>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="blue-box">
    <p>Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! I did it your way and it does work accept now its one individual <div> which I dont need, I need them to be separate.

Comment: add a `margin-right` to the nav or a `margin-left` to the blue-box if you want the to seperate

Comment: alternativly add more code details of the issue then I can help you to integrate it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float or flexbox I actually recommend you use grid

This is your html:

```
<div class="category-tree">
  <nav class="left-menu">
    <ul class="left-menu-categories">
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category"><b>Category</b></a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" title="Category">Category</a></li>
      <hr>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="blue-box">
    <p>Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Grid would allow you to make it super responsive for mobile etc.
Your CSS would look something like this

CSS:

```
category-tree{
 display:grid;
 grid-templates-column: auto auto ;
 /* you can add any padding here as well */
}
```

What happens here is that you are saying the first element inside the major div with class category-tree will be the first element on the left, the next element which is your div with the blue box will be on the right. When you go to work with mobile you can change the css in a media query with the correct sizing then your css would be:

```
category-tree{
     display:grid;
     grid-templates-column: auto ;
     /* you can add any padding here as well */
    }
```

This would be a great way to arrange everything. You can add spacing between them by adding grid-column-gap: 2rem; or any other value you would like. Then with each element you can add padding or anything you need with the other classes you created for each element.